# Ajax call requiring params of previous POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jstl

I've got a bit of a puzzler.

The situation I find myself in:

- I have a `widget.jspf` which was part of a `mainResults.jsp`.
- I've moved `widget.jspf` to be called via ajax in `mainResults.jsp`
- `widget.jspf` relied on request params coming into the original `mainResults.jsp` call.
- uh-oh...

My plan B is to do something very hacky: Have `mainResults.jsp` leave some hidden `<input>s` or something in the resulting html, holding the params needed by `widget.jspf`

I've got 2 questions:

- If I go for plan B (likely due to time constraints), what sort of encoding issues do I need to watch out for? (The jstl will automatically html-encode evaluated params in my input elements? Then my js will need to url-encode them when passed to the jspf? So the jspf needs to unencode those in reverse order?)
- Other than "Don't find yourself in this situation", is there a less hacky plan A? Or is there a better pattern to follow so I don't wind up in this situation? :)

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently. I used your Plan B, sort of. Rather than using hidden inputs I went with the new standard of HTML data (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). Accessible later via JS.

But maybe cookies or an external database storing the data (which can be fetched when needed) are also suitable for you?

Comment: Thanks Jaspa. I ended up going this route. Good call on the data attributes, cleaner than inputs.